# What is meant by "large scale tonal organization?"

Tags: classical-music

I found this in a CD liner note.  "the work shows the influence of Beethoven in its dramatic contrasts and its feeling for large scale tonal organization."

What does this mean?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Large scale tonal organization" refers to planned key relations extended in time. Relating the first and last movement in symphonies for example. Mozart and Beethoven did this a lot.